# Help with php for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Could anyone help me with that php script, I'm very new to php and having troubles with making this code to work

```
 $current = $post->ID;
  $parent = $post->post_parent;
  $grandparent_get = get_post($parent);
  $grandparent = $grandparent_get->post_parent;
  if ($root_parent = get_the_title($grandparent) !== $root_parent = get_the_title($current)) {echo ' <a href="get_permalink($grandparent)">get_the_title($grandparent)</a>';}else {echo '<a href="get_permalink($parent)">get_the_title($parent)</a>';}
```

The last bit from 'if doesnt work i guess there is some syntax problem

Many thanks,

Comment: no but my output is get_the_title($parent) which should be title of the page wrapped in a href

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this, if you are planning on doing any more edits with WP code, I suggest read some PHP basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable does not parsed if they are quoted with single quote.

There are many way to parse them but I am posting one of them try below code

```
echo " <a href=\"get_permalink($grandparent)\">get_the_title($grandparent)</a>";}
else {echo "<a href=\"get_permalink($parent)\">get_the_title($parent)</a>";}
```

OR

```
echo  '<a href="'.get_permalink($grandparent).'">'.get_the_title($grandparent).'</a>';}
else {echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($parent).'">'.get_the_title($parent).'</a>';}
```

Comment: <?php 
 $current = $post->ID;
  $parent = $post->post_parent;
  $grandparent_get = get_post($parent);
  $grandparent = $grandparent_get->post_parent;
  if ($root_parent = get_the_title($grandparent) !== $root_parent = get_the_title($current)) {echo  '<a href="'.get_permalink($grandparent).'">'.get_the_title($grandparent).'</a>';}else {echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($parent).'">'.get_the_title($parent).'</a>';}
       
       
       ?>
That is what i have now and for some reason it breaks page, sorry for being pain

Comment: @jmysona: If it helped accept the answer by clicking on the right arrow besides the answer